# According to the "auto(x)" paper (wg21.link/p0849) , how come "return std::forward<T>" fails to perfect forward the parameters typed with "T&&"?

Tags: c++, auto, type-traits, perfect-forwarding, c++23

The [auto(x)](https://wg21.link/p0849) expression is added to the language. A rational is because we can not perfect forward decay with this.

```
template<class T>
constexpr decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) noexcept(
    is_nothrow_convertible_v<T, decay_t<T>>) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

The `decay_copy` just can not avoid copying, according to the paper https://wg21.link/p0849 .

> An obvious issue is that `decay_copy(x.front())` copies `x.front()` even if `x.front()` is a `prvalue`, in other words, a copy.

Is the `std::forward<T>` supposed to perfect forward the input parameters declared with universal/forwarding reference?

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `return std::forward<T>(v);` is that the returned expression is an xvalue, not a prvalue.
This is not subject to mandatory copy elision (since C++17).

What makes `auto(x)` special, is that if `x` is already a prvalue, then `auto(x)` will simply refer to the same prvalue.
By comparison, `decay_copy(prvalue)` will take an rvalue reference as a parameter, contain a `return xvalue;` statement, and this is a guaranteed copy/move of `v`.

This is obviously not perfect forwarding, because perfect forwarding means that we take expressions and their value categories and move them around with zero overhead, such as a call to a move/copy constructor.

#### What about a `decay_copy` with an *implicit move*?

Interestingly, the `decay_copy` function could be simplified:

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v) noexcept(...) {
    return v;
}
```

> The [*unqualified-id*] expression is an xvalue if it is move-eligible (see below).
> [...]
> An implicitly movable entity is a variable of automatic storage duration that is either a non-volatile object or an **rvalue reference to a non-volatile object type.**
> In the following contexts, an id-expression is move-eligible:
>
> - If the id-expression (possibly parenthesized) is the **operand of a `return` [...]**

- [[expr.prim.id.unqual]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual)

Regardless of whether we return the reference directly or as a result of `std::forward`, this is not subject to copy/move elision, and there is no way to make it so.

#### Notes on NRVO

Sometimes, returning from a function can have the copy/move elided completely, even without prvalues. However, this is not possible here:

> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances:
>
> - (1.1) in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile **object** with automatic storage duration (**other than a function parameter** [...])

- [[class.copy.elision]/1.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1.1)

In the above function, `return v;` is also never eligible for Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO), because `v` is not an object, but a reference.
Even if it was an object, it would be a function parameter and still not eligible.

Comment: If T is `move_constructible`, this means the `decay_copy` function can still do at best "forward by move" only due to [\[expr.prim.id.unqual\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual) ?

Comment: @sandthorn yes. The good news is that `return v;` will move whenever possible. The bad news is that we can't do any better, and that is why we need `auto(x)`.

Comment: That they have to choose this path, is it because destroying the input parameter off-limit of copy elision of c++17 would be a such great burden for the compilers?

Comment: @sandthorn it's impractical to implement this. Consider a function which's definition is not visible to you. How can you know that the function parameter you're constructing is simultaneously the return result at the call site? You would have to optimistically construct the function parameter in the returned object, and then *"evict"* it if this assumption isn't correct. This also wouldn't be legal, because some objects are aware of their own address (for small object optimizations etc.) and cannot be evicted without extra move constructor calls.